# GInfoWindow maxContent dependent on the currently selected tab

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API to display a map and some markers on it. When the user clicks a marker, I use the openInfoWindowTabsHtml of my GMap2 object to display the little balloon, with tabs. I also pass in a maxContent to openInfoWindowTabsHtml, so the baloon becomes maximizable.

Now my problem is, I would like the maximized content to depend on the currently selected tab (basically my maximized content is an extended version of the "short content" I display in the balloon).

I don't really see a way to do that though. I was thinking to catch the maximizeclick event on the info window, and modify the maxContent, just before it gets maximized. But how to modify the maxContent?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was to use tabbedmaxcontent.js from the open source library gmaps-utility-library - http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library - so the maximized balloon has tabs as well.